# one to one distinct restriction on selection

Tags: sql, postgresql

I encountered a problem like that. There are two tables (x value is ordered so that 
in a incremental trend !)

Table A

```
    id     x
    1      1
    1      3
    1      4
    1      7
```

Table B

```
    id     x
    1      2
    1      5
```

I want to join these two tables:
1) on the condition of the equality of id and
2) each row of A should be matched only to one row of B, vice verse (one to one relationship) based on the absolute difference of x value (small difference row has
more priority to match).

Only based on the description above it is not a clear description because if two pairs of row which share a common row in one of the table have the same difference, there is no way to decide which one goes first. So define A as "Main" table, the row in table A with smaller line number always go first

Expected result of demo:

```
    id      A.x     B.x    abs_diff
    1       1       2      1
    1       4       5      1
```

End of table(two extra rows in A shouldn't be considered, because one to one rule)

I am using PostgreSQL so the thing I have tried is DISTINCT ON, but it can not solve.

```
    select distinct on (A.x) id,A.x,B.x,abs_diff
    from
    (A join B
    on A.id=B.id)
    order by A.x,greatest(A.x,B.x)-least(A.x,B.x)
```

Do you have any ideas, it seems to be tricky in plain SQL.

Comment: Please show your query with `distinct on`.

Comment: So, joining on `id` and the minimum difference between `a.x` and `b.x`?  If that is true, then in your example wouldnt the second record's `b.x` be `4`?

Comment: @paqogomez, thank you very much. You are right. should be 4

Comment: So what would be the result for `A(2,5)` and `B(4,7)`? Or for `A(2,4)` and `B(5,7)`? Your question is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select a.id, a.x as ax, b.x as bx, x.min_abs_diff
  from table_a a
  join table_b b
    on a.id = b.id
  join (select a.id, min(abs(a.x - b.x)) as min_abs_diff
          from table_a a
          join table_b b
            on a.id = b.id
         group by a.id) x
    on x.id = a.id
   and abs(a.x - b.x) = x.min_abs_diff
```

fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ab5ae/5/0

Although it doesn't match your expected output, I think the output is correct based on what you described, as you can see each pair has a difference with an absolute value of 1.

Edit - Try the following, based on order of a to b:

```
select *
  from (select a.id,
               a.x as ax,
               b.x as bx,
               x.min_abs_diff,
               row_number() over(partition by a.id, b.x order by a.id, a.x) as rn
          from table_a a
          join table_b b
            on a.id = b.id
          join (select a.id, min(abs(a.x - b.x)) as min_abs_diff
                 from table_a a
                 join table_b b
                   on a.id = b.id
                group by a.id) x
            on x.id = a.id
           and abs(a.x - b.x) = x.min_abs_diff) x
 where x.rn = 1
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ab5ae/19/0

Comment: Hi Brian DeMilla, thank you very much for your answer. But in your solution value 5 in B.x is mapped from A twice which shouldn't be the case.

Comment: Demilla, there was some vagueness in my description. I have updated it. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution for your currently ambiguous question:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
    SELECT id, x AS a, lead(x) OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY x) AS b
    FROM  (
        SELECT *, count(tbl) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY x) AS grp
        FROM  (
            SELECT TRUE AS tbl, * FROM table_a
            UNION ALL
            SELECT NULL, * FROM table_b
            ) x
        ) y
    ) z
WHERE  b IS NOT NULL
ORDER  BY 1,2,3;
```

This way, every `a.x` is assigned the next bigger (or same) `b.x`, unless there is another `a.x` that is still smaller than the next `b.x` (or the same).

Produces the requested result for the demo case. Not sure about various ambiguous cases.

[SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a92d5/2)

Comment: Thank you @Erwin Brandstetter. It solves the example above perfectly. But not my real problem, because in my real problem the column number of table A and table B is not the same and so on. Maybe I just simplified the problem too much. That was my fault